# is it possible to query in memory arrow table using presto or is there some way to use a pandas data frame as a data source for presto query engine

Tags: apache, presto, apache-arrow

is it possible to query in memory arrow table using presto or is there some way to use a pandas data frame as a data source for presto query engine ?

Actually I have parquet files which I want to convert to arrow and query that thorough presto is something like this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, this is not possible. However, there is a Jira open for this feature request. https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/12201